# NullPointerException when i tried to get Extras in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

i have a problem to pass extras between an Activity and a FragmentActivity.

This next code create the Intent to start the new Activity:

```
Intent fichaSerie = new Intent(getActivity(),ActividadSerie.class);
NotificacionSerie serie = (NotificacionSerie) adaptador.getItem(position);
fichaSerie.putExtra("serie", serie.getID());
getActivity().startActivity(fichaSerie);
```

When I tried to get the Extras in the Fragment Activity, i get a NullPointerException:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.serie);
String extra = getIntent().getExtras().getString("serie") //NullPointerException
}
```

Anyone know what mistake(s) i'm made in my code?

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: What type does `serie.getID()` return?

Comment: serie.getID() returns a String

Comment: The exception is generated automatically in the line ````String extra = getIntent().getExtras().getString("serie")```` or is generated within some of those calls. Can you post the stack of the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all your help guys, i solved my problem using this call:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("serie")
```

I mark this question as solved.

Thank you again guys.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Java is case sensitive so `.getID()` is not the same as `.getId()`.
If you are trying to get an ID of an objet, use `.getId()`. That usually returns an `Integer` value

Pay attention on the `type` you are putting to extra as Michal said (String or Integer or anything else)

```
Intent fichaSerie = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActividadSerie.class);
NotificacionSerie serie = (NotificacionSerie) adaptador.getItem(position);
fichaSerie.putExtra("serie", serie.getId()); //presuming this id is an Integer or long int ... You could change this to string if it is still usable then (serie.getId().toString())... but you have to get an intent with myIntent.getStringExtra(...), but I think you will not be doing this.
startActivityForResult(fichaSerie, 0);
```

Getting an extra from ActividadSerie.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.serie);
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String extra = myIntent.getStringExtra("serie"); //try diferent gets... getIntExtra(), getStringExtra()..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but getID() method returns a String chain hence i used putString method

Comment: then use `String extra = myIntent.getStringExtra("serie");` in the ActividadSerie.java

Comment: I'm doing exactly that but i get a nullpointerException, hence i wrote my question

Answer (score 0):

You are put an `Integer` value and get it into the `String` value so that it gets a `NullPointerException`.